# Array Collection not populated when generating fixtures

Tags: symfony, fixtures, nelmio-alice

I have fixtures (alice) who are populating an array collection (OneToMany) like :

```
types: ['@type1', '@type2', '@typeSpecific']
```

The problem is that stuff are not taken into account and when i'm testing my code, i see that all the other fields are populated, but this $types is an empty collection. Someone have experienced that ?

Thank you devs.

Comment: let me know your launching order fixtures

Comment: the loaded file (who contains 'types: ['@type1', ...]') is including the yml file who contain 'type1:...'

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

In the relation related entity, addType should be implemented like :

```
$this->types[] = $type;

$type->setMyRelation($this);
```